# Capture form post in asp.net - VS2008

Tags: asp.net

I have a 3rd party submitting data via form post. I want to capture the contents of the post without actually doing

```
Request[FormElementName"].ToString()
```

for every element that i am expecting

Is there some method/property in the Request object which would allow me to capture the entire form post? Something similar to

```
Request.RawUrl.ToString()
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Request.Form` property returns a NameValueCollection containing all the posted parameters.

You could do something as simple as :

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
foreach (string key in nvc.AllKeys)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Key - " + key);
  Debug.WriteLine("Value - " + nvc[key]);
  Debug.WriteLine("---");
}
```

**Edit:** If you need to query QueryString values as well, use the `Request.Params` property in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all posted elements by **Page.Request.Form** collection.